# Which the versions of Tomcat and JBoss servers support CDI integration?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, cdi

1) I want to know which versions of the Tomcat and JBoss servers support the CDI because I need to do a migration of applications that run on Tomcat 5

2) Where the integrations is better, in Tomcat or JBoss?

**P.S:** the application in question isn't distributed, has Struts, JSP, Servlet, DWR and JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

1) CDI is supported only from Tomcat 6, however according to JBoss [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_tomcat) the current supported versions for Weld (CDI reference implementation) are just 7 and 8.

2) Integration would be easier with JBoss EAP (support from EAP 5) or Wildfly, however if you don't need any Java EE technologies I would go with more lightweight server like Tomcat or Jetty. Only downside  is that you have to do some tweaks in your application in order to use CDI under Tomcat or Jetty. Nice article about configuring CDI in Tomcat is [this one](http://balusc.blogspot.cz/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html)

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat doesn't support CDI out of the box. You will need to configure it manually. If you are looking for server that provides it and is lightweight, you may check also [WebSphere Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/introducing_the_liberty_profile/), which is modularized and allows you easily select what you need from Java EE stack, without fighting with 3rd party libraries.